# Join to Stored Procedure Using Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, stored-procedures, join, recursive-query

I have a stored procedure that grabs data recursively. I did a function import in my entity set. I can create a function in my ObjectContext that looks like this:

```
public ObjectResult<ProviderAccountSetting> GetProviderAccountSettings(long providerAccountId)
{
    string functionName = "MyContainer.GetProviderAccountSettings";
    ObjectParameter providerAccountIdParameter = new ObjectParameter("providerAccountId", providerAccountId);
    ObjectResult<ProviderAccountSetting> results = context.ExecuteFunction<ProviderAccountSetting>(functionName, providerAccountIdParameter);
    return results;
}
```

However, I cannot perform a join with LINQ without getting an error. Is there a way to tell Entity Framework to use the stored procedure whenever I access an entity? I would like my stored procedure to be used *any time* I grab data for that entity. Furthermore, I want it to work with joins. Does Entity Framework support this type of stored-procedure to table mapping? Otherwise, is there a way to join a function import?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neither of your requirement is possible. You cannot tell EF to use stored procedure every time when you query data. You must manually call your `GetProviderAccountSettings` to call stored procedure. You also cannot use join (on database side) when using stored procedures (it is even not possible in SQL directly). If you need to join any data to result set of your stored procedure it must be done directly in the procedure and returned as result set. Otherwise you must execute your stored procedure and joined query separately and join them in linq-to-objects.